# Ionic 2 push notification stopped after CLI upgrade to 3.12.0

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ionic2

I have an application developed with Ionic 2, the Ionic itself is no upgraded, but I upgraded the CLI from 2.2.1 to 3.12.0 for App startup performance enhancement (it went down from 9 seconds to 2 seconds).
Nevertheless, I have a problem that the push notifications no longer arrive or at least no longer appear in the status bar if it arrives. I build an Android apk and installed it on the phone and discovered this behaviour.

I am on "cordova": "6.5.0" - "@ionic-native/push": "^3.6.1"

Any help would be very useful, I sure can post more code snippets if required.

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "author": "author",
  "homepage": "https://homepage.com",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ionic-serve": "ionic serve",
    "build-dev": "ionic-app-scripts build --dev",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
    "serve:before": "watch",
    "emulate:before": "build",
    "deploy:before": "build",
    "build:before": "build",
    "run:before": "build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/deeplinks": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/push": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.0.0",
    "bourbon": "^4.3.3",
    "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.7.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.26.1",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.4",
    "cordova": "6.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    },
    {
      "platform": "android",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "android"
    }
  ],
  "description": "ion2-FullApp: An Ionic project",
  "config": {
    "ionic_sass": "./config/sass.config.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add the package.json?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the plugin?

Comment: yes, I reinstalled the plugin. Actually I removed the plugins folder and recreated it. If I use the 2.2.1 CLI to build, the push notifications work.

Comment: I added the json to the main post